# Is there a cleaner, shorter, built-in way to wrap elements in an iterable in ruby?

Tags: ruby

This code works:

```
permission.class.ancestors.include?(Enumerable) ? permission : [permission]
```

The content in `permission` can either by a symbol or any sequence (say, an array). If a single element is passed, it is wrapped in an array.

Is there a method already doing this? (May be either ruby-built-in in 2.2.2 or added by rails 4.2.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it seems like you're describing the `Array.wrap()` extension provided by ActiveSupport in in Rails (`active_support/core_ext`):

```
>> list = ['a', :b, /c/]
=> ["a", :b, /c/]

>> Array.wrap(list)
=> ["a", :b, /c/]

>> map = {"a" => :foo, b: :bar, /c/ => 'baz'}
=> {"a"=>:foo, :b=>:bar, /c/=>"baz"}

>> Array.wrap(map)
=> [{"a"=>:foo, :b=>:bar, /c/=>"baz"}]

>> Array.wrap(:symbol_literal)
=> [:symbol_literal]
```

You can find the documentation here: http://apidock.com/rails/Array/wrap/class. 
The `Array(...)` method in the core Ruby library has similar behavior, but will convert a hash to a nested array:

```
>> Array(list)
=> ["a", :b, /c/]

>> Array(map)
=> [["a", :foo], [:b, :bar], [/c/, "baz"]]  # Probably not what you want

>> Array(:symbol_literal)
=> [:symbol_literal]
```

The documentation in the link provided above contains a more comprehensive explanation of `Array.wrap()` vs `Array()`